# If $|\alpha|_1 < 1 \implies |\alpha|_2 < 1$ for two valuations, are they equivalent?

Tags: ring-theory, commutative-algebra, field-theory, algebraic-number-theory, valuation-theory

I've come across the following claim in [these notes](https://www.math.ucla.edu/~sharifi/algnum.pdf) (pg 87, proof of 5.2.35).

> **Claim:** If $K$ is a field, with $|\cdot|_1$ and $|\cdot|_2$ two inequivalent valuations (positive definite, multiplicative, satisfies triangle inequality) on $K$, then there exist elements $\alpha$ and $\beta$ such that 
>   $$|\alpha|_1 < 1, \quad |\alpha|_2 \ge 1,$$
>   and 
>   $$|\beta|_2 < 1,\quad |\beta|_1 \ge 1.$$

The notes claim that this follows from Prop 5.2.5, the relevant part of which appears to be that $|\cdot |_1$ and $|\cdot |_2$ are equivalent if and only if 
$$|\alpha|_1 < 1 \iff |\alpha|_2<1. $$
Then the inequivalence of the valuations tells us that there is 
$\alpha$ such that either $|\alpha|_1 < 1$ and $|\alpha|_2\ge 1$, or 
$|\alpha|_2 < 1$ and $|\alpha|_1 \ge 1$. Thus we can find either $\alpha$ or $\beta$, but its not clear that we can find both.

Being able to find both $\alpha$ and $\beta$ appears to be equivalent to the claim that if $|\alpha|_1 < 1 \implies |\alpha|_2 < 1$, then the valuations 
are equivalent.

Thus I'm attempting to either

1. prove $|\alpha|_1 < 1 \implies |\alpha|_2 < 1$ tells us that the valuations are equivalent,
2. or disprove (1) and prove directly that if the valuations are inequivalent, then there exists $\alpha$ with $|\alpha|_1 < 1$ and $|\alpha|_2 > 1$, which is what the notes are using the claim for.

**Progress on proof/disproof:**

If $|\alpha|_2 < 1$, then $|1/\alpha|_2 > 1$, so 
$|1/\alpha|_1 \ge 1$. Thus $|\alpha|_1 \le 1$.

However, I can't seem to prove that we can't have 
$|\alpha|_1 = 1$.

For non archimedean valuations, I tried thinking about this in terms of valuation rings.
Let $\newcommand\calO{\mathcal{O}}\calO_i = \{ a\in K : |a|_i \le 1 \}.$
Then $\calO_2 \subseteq \calO_1$. Let $\newcommand{\mm}{\mathfrak{m}}\mm_i$ be the maximal ideals of $\calO_i$. We know $\mm_1 \subseteq \mm_2$.
So suppose $x\in \calO_1\setminus \calO_2$. Then $|x|_1 = 1$ and 
$|x|_2 > 1$. Then $y=1/x$ has $|y|_1 = 1$ and $|y|_2 < 1$, so $y\in \mm_2\setminus \mm_1$. Hence if the rings are not equal, 
$\mm_2$ is a proper ideal.

This seems to be completely possible if $\newcommand\pp{\mathfrak{p}}\pp$ is a prime ideal inside the maximal ideal of a valuation ring, then localizing at $\pp$ should produce a valuation ring, and the associated valuations should be inequivalent, yet satisfy the given property. However, I'm not very familiar with valuation rings, and I don't have a concrete example of how this would work.

**Related questions**

There appears to be [this related question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/99832/90543), which appears to suggest that the answer is affirmative, rather than negative as my prior paragraph is leading me to believe.

The crucial issue, as in why it's not helping me, is that I can't figure out how the three implications in the question body were derived.

Comment: Note that $\alpha,\beta$ are not related in anyway. In your deduction of the existence of $\alpha$ such that $|\alpha|_1 < 1, |\alpha|_2 \ge 1$, swap $|\cdot|_1$ with $|\cdot|_2$ everywhere to obtain the existence of $\beta$.

Comment: @pisco the deduction I have only tells me that one or the other exists without producing one in particular, so I can't apply symmetry. That's why I was trying to prove the thing I'm asking about.

Comment: Can you make "valuation" more precise (don't confuse with absolute value) ? $v(0) = \infty, v(x)=0,x\in \Bbb{Q}^*$ is a valuation and it is not equivalent to the $p$-adic one. If $v_1,v_2$ are two non-trivial discrete valuations $k\to \Bbb{Q}\cup \infty$ and $\forall a\in k, v_2(a)\ge v_1(a)$ then $O_{v_2}\subset O_{v_1}$ and since for any $x\in k-O_{v_2}$ we have $k = O_{v_2}[x]$, if $O_{v_1}\supsetneq O_{v_2}$ then $O_{v_1} = k$, a contradiction. Thus $O_{v_1}=O_{v_2}$ which implies $v_1=r v_2$ for some $r\in \Bbb{Q}$.

Comment: The difference between (non-archimedian) valued field and discretely valued field is with the valuation $v$ from $ Frac(k[x,y])$ to the ordered abelian group $\Bbb{Z+\epsilon Z}$ defined by $v(\sum_{n,m}c_{n,m} x^ny^m ) = \inf_{c_{n,m}\ne 0} n+\epsilon m$ whose $O_v=k[y]_{(y)}+xk[x]_{(x)}(y)$ has the prime ideals $(0),(x),(x,y)$. When assuming the valuation gives a real valued absolute value you avoid that case.

Comment: @reuns The notes here make a distinction between a multiplicative valuation and an additive valuation. The multiplicative valuation being an absolute value on the field, i.e., a function $K \to \Bbb{R}_{\ge 0}$ which is positive definite ($|x|=0\iff x=0$), multiplicative ($|ab|=|a||b|$), and satisfies triangle inequality ($|a+b|\le |a| + |b|$).

Comment: Also the valuation you give with $v(0)=\infty$, $v(x)=0$ for $x\in \Bbb{Q}^\times$ should correspond to the trivial absolute value $|x|=1$ for $x\ne 0$, and I should've clarified that we are assuming that all absolute values are nontrivial.

Comment: @reuns, I follow your argument for the discrete valuations, thank you. However, there should be valuations (absolute values) which take values in $\Bbb{R}$ that are not discrete, right? Perhaps I'm misinterpreting your second comment, but you seem to be saying that that is not the case. Thank you for your comments.

Comment: Yes, for example $k[[x]][x^{1/\infty}]$ has value group $\Bbb{Q}$  and $v(x)=1,v(y)=\pi$ is a non-discrete valuation on $Frac(k[x,y])$.  
In your question $O_2$ has a unique non-zero prime ideal $P$ because with $d\in P,v(d) >0$, for all $v(c) > 0$ then $v(c^n)>v(d)$ implies $c^n\in P O_2$ thus $c\in P$.
Equivalently, for two non-trivial valuation $k \to \Bbb{R}$ such that $v_2\ge v_1$, take $a\in k$, $v_2(a)=r v_1(a) \ne 0$ then for all $b\in k,n,m, v_2(a^m/b^n)\ge v_1(a^m/b^n)$ implies $v_2(b)=rv_1(b)$ and $v_2=rv_1$.

Comment: Sorry to be pedantic, but the assertion is trivially false if one of the absolute values $\lvert \cdot \rvert_i$ is trivial. With that case excluded, it's true (but that means one would have to use somewhere that both values are non-trivial).